# How do I autoresize the Form so that its control will not have scrollbar

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I have a Form which contains only a DataGridView which is docked fill.
The DataGridView only has one column and the row can be many.

I have only a small data to display.
Here is a sample data:

[image]

I want the form to auto size its height so that the vertical scroll bar wont be displayed.

Here is my code:

```
    public RowDetailsForm(DataGridViewRow row, DataGridViewColumnCollection cols, int localizationFoldersCount)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.row = row;
        this.cols = cols;
        this.localizationFoldersCount = localizationFoldersCount;
        CreateDetails();
    }

    private void CreateDetails()
    {
        detailDataGridView.Rows.Add(row.Cells["keyColumn"].Value.ToString());
        detailDataGridView.Rows[detailDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1].HeaderCell.Value = "Translation Key";

        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            if (cell.ColumnIndex != 0 && cell.Value != null)
            {
                string cellText = cell.Value.ToString();
                string rowHeaderText = cols[cell.ColumnIndex].HeaderText;
                if (cellText != "" && cols.Count - localizationFoldersCount <= cell.ColumnIndex)
                {
                    cellText = cellText.Substring(1, cellText.Length - 2).Replace("][", Environment.NewLine);

                    string pattern = Environment.NewLine;
                    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(cellText, pattern);
                    rowHeaderText += "(" + (matches.Count + 1) + ")";
                }
                detailDataGridView.Rows.Add(cellText);
                detailDataGridView.Rows[detailDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1].HeaderCell.Value = rowHeaderText;
            }
        }            
    }
```

How is this coded?

Comment: did u try?  this.AutoSize = true;
      this.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;

Comment: i tried that, but the rows in my datagridview are dynamically created. The form became so small

Comment: I see. try this.Invalidate() after AutoSize , AutoSizeMode each time

Comment: show yr code, I want to simulate it and to help u better

Comment: I have added my code

Answer (score 0):

You need to measure exactly how many pixels need for the form height in order to contain the `detailDataGridView` inside your form.
 you must do it after you set the number of rows,in that example the form will fit it self to the datagridview height and scrollbar will be unnecessary.
 please read my comments in the example:

```
private void ResizeDgv()
{
    detailDataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    // discover max form (screen) height.
   var maxHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
    // discover forms title height
    Rectangle screenrectange = this.RectangleToScreen(this.ClientRectangle);
    var titleheight = screenrectange.Top - this.Top;
    // discover datagridview columns height
    var colHeight = detailDataGridView.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Size.Height;
    // discover total rows height
    var totalRowsHeight = detailDataGridView.RowCount * detailDataGridView.Rows[0].HeaderCell.Size.Height;
    // discover borders height
    var borders = System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.FrameBorderSize.Height * 3;
    // total height needed
    var total = totalRowsHeight + colHeight + titleheight + borders;

    if (total > maxHeight)
    {
        // extreme case: There is no way to avoid scrollbar - max screen hight is less the datagridview calculated height
        this.Size = new Size(this.Width, maxHeight);
    }
    else
    {
        // resize forms height according to total height
        this.Size = new Size(this.Width, total);
    }
}
```